# How to monitor log files and set up an alert based on keywords using Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Recently, I just started to learn Elastic Search and I found it provides several monitoring and alerting function. For example, users can create a watcher to monitor a certain metric, a alert will be triggered if it exceeds the threshold. 
Meanwhile, Elastic Search is designed for full text searching.

I wonder whether I can monitor log files and set up an alert based on eywords? For example, the alert triggered by the keyword "test", if the incoming log file contains word "test", the alert will be triggered.

If somebody have done anything related or have a clue about this, please give me a hint!